# Abstract algebra homomorphism question

Tags: abstract-algebra

This was a question on my abstract algebra test. I didn't know what to do with it.

Let $\phi:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_8$, such that $\phi(1) = 6$. For what values of $n$ does $\phi(n) = 0$?
This is a homomorphism.

I listed the multiples of $8$, since they are all equal to $0\bmod 8$. That's obviously wrong, though, and I should be ashamed.

Comment: All of the multiples of 8 are acceptable values of $n$; it's just that there are also other values of $n$. However, it's a good guess, so I do not think you should be ashamed.

Comment: There is no person on the planet (including babies) who is worse at abstract than me. Thanks for the encouragement. I really hope that I remembered the question correctly. I somehow doubt it.

Comment: So the phi(1) = 6 is just to throw people off? I should've listed the relatively prime values. I'm not sure why I didn't.

Comment: No, the $\phi(1)=6$ is important, too, as shown by the below answers. Also, abstract algebra is hard to get used to, but I'm sure that you'll get better over time! Just don't lose hope!

Comment: Too late. Abstract is for the smart people.

Answer (score 1):

We have $\phi(n)=\phi(1+1+\cdots+1)=n\phi(1)=6n$.

To find $\ker \phi$, we must solve $6n \equiv 0 \bmod 8$.

This equation reduces to $3n \equiv 0 \bmod 4$, or $n \equiv 0 \bmod 4$.

Therefore, $\ker \phi = 4\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 1):

Start by applying the homomorphism axioms:

We have $\phi(1) = 6$, so $\phi(1+1) = \phi(1) + \phi(1) = 6 + 6$, and $\phi(1+1+1) = \phi(1) + \phi(1) + \phi(1) = 6+6+6$, and so forth (all reduced mod $8$ of course).  When do we hit $0 \pmod{8}$?  When $\phi(n) = n \times 6$ is a multiple of $8$ when unreduced.

Notice that the first $n$ for which this happens will satisfy $n \times 6 = \displaystyle \operatorname{lcm}(6, 8) = \frac{6 \times 8}{\gcd(6, 8)}$.

Once we've wrapped around to zero, the cycle repeats itself.

Using this logic, you should convince yourself that, in general, if we have a homomorphism $\phi:\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_m$ defined where $\phi(1) = k$, then the integers $n$ such that $\phi(n) = 0$ are precisely the multiples of $\operatorname{lcm}(k, m)$.

Answer (score 1):

The trick here is the following:
$$\phi(n) = \phi(1+1+1+1+...+1) = \phi(1)+\phi(1)+\phi(1)+...\phi(1) = n\cdot\phi(1)$$
Regardless of what the homomorphism is, if the domain is the additive group of $\Bbb{Z}$, then we have $\phi(n)=n\cdot \phi(1)$. This is a really important hint in a lot of abstract algebra problems. In this problem, it gives us the following:
$$\phi(n) \equiv n\cdot \phi(1) \equiv 6n \pmod 8$$

Thus, we need to solve $6n \equiv 0 \pmod 8$, which is the same as:
$$6n=8k \text{ (for some} k \in \Bbb{Z} \text{)}$$
Divide both sides by $2$:
$$3n=4k \text{ (for some} k \in \Bbb{Z} \text{)}$$
Turn back into a modulo equation:
$$3n \equiv 0 \pmod 4$$
Multiply both sides by $3$ since $3 \cdot 3 \equiv 1 \pmod 4$:
$$n \equiv 0 \pmod 4$$
Thus, the answer is all multiples of 4, not just the multiples of 8.

Comment: I'm still confused. 44 is a multiple of 4 but is equal to 4, not 0, in mod 8.

Comment: The question asks if $\phi(n) \equiv 0 \pmod 8$. If you look at the top of your answer, we have: $$\phi(n) \equiv 6n \pmod 8$$ Therefore: $$\phi(44) \equiv 6\cdot 44 \equiv 264 \equiv 0 \pmod 8$$ Thus, $\phi(44) \equiv 0 \pmod 8$, which is why $n=44$ is a solution.

Comment: I still say this is a little too challenging for 55 minutes (with 2 other proofs/hard questions, plus other questions). Yeah, I get it, it's college, but come on.

Comment: @T-1000'sSon It is definitely challenging if the teacher has not taught $\phi(n)=n\cdot \phi(1)$, but other than that, if you understand the concept of homomorphisms and how to manipulate modulo equations, I think this is a reasonable question. Of course, if there are other hard questions worth more points and you only have 55 minutes, then this question might be the one to skip.

Comment: It was worth 12 points. She taught us about homomorphisms, but nothing really like this. I think she has to give me some credit. I did get part of the answer correct.

Comment: @T-1000 In most cases the credit she gives is totally up to her, so you have to play her game, she doesn't have to play yours. That's another feature of college.

Comment: @MattSamuel Yeah but most people have morals about this. A good proof is usually a good proof regardless. Also there are deans and department heads and ratemyprofessors.com

Comment: @Alephnull That's why I said in most cases. A Dean or a department head will do nothing unless it is extremely, outstandingly obvious that the grading was egregiously wrong, and I can't imagine how that could ever happen, at least at my school.

Comment: @MattSamuel Yeah I think you're right. Its just a slightly lighter "have to" makes many actually do their job. Also you can always go to office hours or disrupt class to get your way.

Comment: You don't have to be patronizing, Matt. I'm aware of how college works.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\phi(1)=6$ and $\phi$ is a homomorphism under additive notation, $\phi(4)=\phi(1+1+1+1)=\phi(1)+\phi(1)+\phi(1)+\phi(1)=[6]+[6]+[6]+[6]=[24]=[0]$.
This is effectively saying that $ker(\phi)={4n:n\in\mathbb{Z}}$. So all multiples of 4 in $\mathbb{Z}$ will be mapped to $[0]$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{8}$

Comment: Won't all multiples of 2 also map to 0?

Comment: $\phi(2)=\phi(1)+\phi(1)=[6]+[6]=[12]=[4]\neq[0]$

Comment: So not all multiples of 2 gets mapped to [0]

Answer (score -1):

f(1)=6. f(4)=24=0 . 4 is the least in absolute value that maps to 0. 4Z maps to 0.